# JNA - Mapping int* from 32bits DLL loaded in 64bits Java

Tags: java, c++, dll, jna

I'm facing a problem trying to map a 32bit COM DLL (wrote in OLD C++) method using 64bit Java.

The COM DLL expose this method (I check this using OLEViewer):

```
void Login(
                [out] int* ResultCode, 
                [out] BSTR* Result, 
                [in] BSTR App, 
                [in, out] BSTR* User, 
                [in] BSTR Module, 
                [in] BSTR Password, 
                [out] BSTR* Permissions, 
                [out] BSTR* Data1, 
                [out] BSTR* Data2, 
                [out] BSTR* Data3, 
                [out] BSTR* Data4, 
                [out] BSTR* Data5, 
                [out] int* UserLevel, 
                [out] int* ExpirationDays, 
                [in] int Authentication);
```

I was succesfully mapped 'Result' param as BSTRByReference, I run the method and receive in that param the value modified by Login, but I'm not able to map the 'ResultCode' param (or any other [out] int*), it always remains in NULL value.

I tried using IntByReference (type mismatch error), ShortByReference, byte, etc. with no luck.

The creepy part is that DLL is 32bits and I followed these steps to be able to load it in Java using JNA:

https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/

Is it possible to load a 32bits DLL in 64bits Java without any consequence, or maybe that's why I'm having troubles with the mapping?

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE JAVA CLASS]

```
    /**
     * method Login
     *
     * <p>id(0x3)</p>
     * <p>vtableId(9)</p>
     * @param ResultCode [out] {@code Integer}
     * @param Result [out] {@code String}
     * @param App [in] {@code String}
     * @param User [inout] {@code String}
     * @param Module [in] {@code String}
     * @param Password [in] {@code String}
     * @param Permissions [out] {@code String}
     * @param Data1 [out] {@code String}
     * @param Data2 [out] {@code String}
     * @param Data3 [out] {@code String}
     * @param Data4 [out] {@code String}
     * @param Data5 [out] {@code String}
     * @param UserLevel [out] {@code Integer}
     * @param ExpirationDays [out] {@code Integer}
     * @param Authentication [in] {@code Integer}
     */
    @ComMethod(name = "Login", dispId = 0x3)
    void Login(VARIANT ResultCode,
            BSTRByReference Result,
            String App,
            String User,
            String Module,
            String Password,
            VARIANT Permissions,
            VARIANT Data1,
            VARIANT Data2,
            VARIANT Data3,
            VARIANT Data4,
            VARIANT Data5,
            VARIANT UserLevel,
            VARIANT ExpirationDays,
            Integer Authentication);
```

That is the JAVA class that TlbCodeGenerator creates from COM DLL.
As you can see, ResultCode is detected as VARIANT.
I tried using VARIANT.ByReference and didnt work, also tried with ShortByReference, Pointer, short[], ByteByReference, byte, etc.

[UPDATE JAVA Login() CALL]

```
    Factory factory = new Factory();
    Security isec = factory.createObject(Security.class);

    BSTR bstr_tmp = OleAuto.INSTANCE.SysAllocString("");
    BSTRByReference res = new BSTRByReference(bstr_tmp);
    ShortByReference res_code2 = new ShortByReference();
    
    // I left these fields as VARIANT because I'm not using them in test
    VARIANT.ByReference permisos = new VARIANT.ByReference();
    VARIANT.ByReference data1 = new VARIANT.ByReference();
    VARIANT.ByReference data2 = new VARIANT.ByReference();
    VARIANT.ByReference data3 = new VARIANT.ByReference();
    VARIANT.ByReference data4 = new VARIANT.ByReference();
    VARIANT.ByReference data5 = new VARIANT.ByReference();
    VARIANT.ByReference nivel = new VARIANT.ByReference();
    VARIANT.ByReference exp = new VARIANT.ByReference();

    isec.Login(res_code2, res, "XXXX", "UUUUU", "SSSS", "PPPPP", permisos, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, nivel, exp, 2);
```

After isec.Login() call I have 'res' variable filled with a result text (i.e.: "OK.", "ERROR XXX", etc.) and 'res_code2' is 0 (I should have a result code in
'res_code2' like 0x70d1)

[OLE VIEWER DISPLAY]
[image: OLEVIEWER]

[UPDATE TRYING WITH Connect()]

OLE Method:

```
[id(0x00000001), helpstring("method Connect")]
    HRESULT Connect(
                    [out] int* ResultCode, 
                    [out] BSTR* Result, 
                    [in] BSTR Host, 
                    [in] short Port);
```

JAVA Class:

```
    /**
     * method Connect
     *
     * <p>id(0x1)</p>
     * <p>vtableId(7)</p>
     * @param ResultCode [out] {@code Integer}
     * @param Result [out] {@code String}
     * @param Host [in] {@code String}
     * @param Port [in] {@code Short}
     */
    @ComMethod(name = "Connect", dispId = 0x1)
    void Connect(ShortByReference ResultCode,
            BSTRByReference Result,
            BSTR Host,
            Short Port);
```

Call:

```
        Factory factory = new Factory();
        Security isec = factory.createObject(Security.class);
        
        ShortByReference res_code = new ShortByReference();

        BSTR res_bstr = OleAuto.INSTANCE.SysAllocString("");
        BSTRByReference res = new BSTRByReference(res_bstr);
        
        BSTR host = OleAuto.INSTANCE.SysAllocString("XXX.XX.XXX.184");
        Short port = 5000;

        isec.Connect(res_code, res, host, port);
        // Here I can see that the connect() works fine, but I did not receive
        // the res_code value
```

Comment: Please show your actual Java code that is not working for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau just added the code. I tried several types but no one works, also to know that the method does not throw any error, it works as expected but ResultCode value is never modified.

Comment: `VARIANT` is definitely the wrong thing to use here, as there are no `VARIANT`s present in the COM object's actual declaration. Also, all of the `[in,out] BSTR*` and `[out] BSTR*` parameters should be `BSTRByReference`, and the `[out] int*` parameters should be `IntByReference`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that was my first though, but if I use IntByReference it throws an exception  "Type mismatch". So I guess that Int type size in Java could be bigger than int type in COM DLL, then I used ShortByReference no "Type mismatch" is throwed, the method runs ok, but the value is not being modified by the method...

Comment: That implies that the COM object is written in a VERY OLD compiler that used a 16-bit `int`, whereas modern compilers use a 32-bit `int` instead. "*the value is not being modified by the method*" - that is a separate issue.  Can you please show the Java code that is actually calling `Login()`? Can you also please show the actual OleViewer display?

Comment: @RemyLebeau question updated with call code. Yes, its a VERY VERY OLD DLL, compiled in c++ but possibily more than 15 years ago.

Comment: @RemyLebeau to be more specific, the COM DLL was compiled with VC++6 :S

Comment: Your use of `String` for the 4 arguments `App`, `User`, `Module`, and `Password` looks wrong.  Three of those are `BSTR` which you need to allocate with `OleAuto.INSTANCE.SysAllocString()`.  You can't pass a plain String, it needs the length prefix, and the `User` should be a `BSTRByReference`.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I have tried all combinations and it did not work. I added as example the Connect() method which is simpler than Login(). As you can see I pass the args as BSTR and BSTRByReference but it did not work.

Comment: In the second call you used `ShortByReference` for the result code. It's an `int*` which is `IntByReference`. And you should use `HRESULT` return, not `void`.

Comment: @DanielWiddis as I said before, if I use IntByReference it throws me an exception "Type mismatch", I suspect it's because the DLL was compiled in VC++6 32bits, so Int size is bigger than it expects. That's why I used ShortByReference, expecting that match the arg size.

Comment: Got it, there was so much info I was getting confused.  I'm now as baffled as you are.  It's possible FFI (how JNA interfaces via C) can't handle whatever call stack ABI that DLL expects.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I'm pretty lost with this... I will try to run java in 32bits and check if then I can use IntByReference. Thanks both of you for your comments.